# Where is the implementation code for the Map class in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm looking into the map.dart source code. However, I couldn't find where the implementation codes of the functions below were.

```
external factory Map();

V? operator [](Object? key);

void clear();
```

And why is the factory keyword used in the constructor of Map?

Comment: `Map`'s uses a `factory` constructor so that it can return an instance of a `LinkedHashMap` as the default `Map` implementation. (Meanwhile, `LinkedHashMap` also uses `factory` constructors so that it can return a different implementation for the Dart VM than for Dart for the web.) For the Dart VM implementation, see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/stable/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/map_patch.dart, and https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/stable/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/collection_patch.dart, https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/stable/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/compact_hash.dart.

Comment: In general, see [how to access the source code of built in methods of Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62131787/)